# Three operators commuting with each other

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

It is well known that if two operators commute, the it is possible to find common eigenfucntions for them. What if we have 3 operators that commute with each other? Will we find common eigenfunctions for all of them at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example, when calculating angular momentum of a hydrogen atom (ignoring fine structure or hyperfine structure), the eigenbases (which are described by spherical harmonics) are simultaneously eigenbases of the Hamiltonian operator $H$, the total angular momentum operator $L^2$, and the z-component angular momentum operator $L_z$.

The proof can be constructed based on the proof for just 2 operators (for example, see [here](http://people.physics.tamu.edu/herschbach/commuting%20observables%20and%20simultaneous%20eigenfunctions.pdf)), with essentially the same steps for the nondegenerate case. For some of the degenerate cases, the difference is that the eigensubspace is now at least 3-dimensional instead of 2-dimensional.

Comment: Giving one example does not constitute a proof.

Comment: @tparker I have modified my answer to include a very rough proof sketch; I have not tried it myself, but I don't see any roadblock for the 3 operator case that makes it different from the 2 operator case.